# VM gives many errors when run

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to run my app in the android emulator when an error popped out

> F/flutter ( 6670): [FATAL:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(416)] Error while
>   initializing the Dart VM: Wrong full snapshot version, expected
>   '0c73eb70aa4d30f450273cb424be8c62' found
>   'e7c8a6096e8cb3ada7a6550e3f87ea88'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded from Android 10.0 to 9.0 and I solved the problem!